# Can we provide a project url which is hosted locally as the 'source site' while creating a moovweb project?

Tags: moovweb

Will it be possible to create a moovweb project by providing url of the local project as source site value??Is it necessary that the site should be live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `config.json` file in your Moovweb project so that the right-hand side mapping is a local path. For example:

```
{
  "host_map": [
    "$.mylocalsite.com => localhost:3000",
    "anotherlocaladdress.com => localhost:9292"
  ]
}
```

You can actually put any path in the left-hand side as well. This will just translate into a modification in your computer's `hosts` file. The `$` symbol denotes the `-host-var` parameter that you can run the server with. If you don't specify this parameter, it will default to `mlocal`. Notice there is no `$` in the second entry. This just means that path will not be dependent on the `-host-var` parameter.

Once you start the server with `moov server`, the entries in `config.json` will result in these entries in your `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 mlocal.mylocalsite.com
127.0.0.1 anotherlocaladdress.com
```

If you specify the `-host-var` parameter to be `mtest`, the resulting entries will be:

```
127.0.0.1 mtest.mylocalsite.com
127.0.0.1 anotherlocaladdress.com
```

You will also see the related `.moovapp.com` entries; these are mapped automatically for testing purposes.

The default ports that `moov server` runs at include 80, 443, 3003, and 8004, but you can modify these to suit your local environment. If you want to run other local servers, make sure they do not conflict.

The caveat is none of this will work if you try to push to the Moovweb Cloud. Remember to change the mapping to reflect an actual live URL when you're ready.

Comment: @gregorygseng - I too am having issue while testing my sample project (using blog.moovdemos.com) on moovweb cloud. I have posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119432/no-such-host-mesage-while-site-is-deployed-on-moovapp-com-domain). I am sure I have misunderstood something.