# "no such host" mesage while site is deployed on moovapp.com domain

Tags: moovweb

I have done a sample project based on **blog.moovdemos.com** to test the [moovweb](http://developer.moovweb.com/) solution.

After testing it on on local system I deployed the project on moovweb cloud. I have learnt that one need to own the domain to be able to access it from internet. However, as per [documentation](http://developer.moovweb.com/docs/cloud/production_domain), it is still available within moovapp.com domain.

While I am trying to access my site through moovapp.com domain I get moovweb warning page as below

> Warning: the webpage you are attempting to access is a Moovweb
> Remixed™ version of mshruthijanardhan14047.blog.moovdemos.com. Should
> you choose to continue, Moovweb is not responsible for the contents of
> this webpage.
> [Agree and continue] [Decline]

However, on chossing **[Agree and continue]** I get following message instead of site page

> Failed to establish a connection with upstream (dial tcp: lookup
> *[muser1234]*.blog.moovdemos.com: no such host)

please help me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a misconfigured `config.json` file in your project.

On the right-hand side of the first "host_map" value, you will need to put the upstream domain 'blog.moovdemos.com'. You currently have it set to `[muser1234].blog.moovdemos.com`. This domain does not exist; that is why you are getting the "dial tcp: lookup ... no such host" error.

The correct setting should look like:

```
"host_map": [
    "$.blog.moovdemos.com => blog.moovdemos.com"
]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I checked my local config.json and indeed that was the mistake. Now I have corrected it and redployed the code, 'no such host' error is disappeared but page is blank!

Comment: Do you see the content when you run the SDK locally?

Comment: Can you show me what mixers you are using in your `Mixer.lock` file?

Comment: Yes, locally I can see the portal but its blank only after uploading on cloud. Mixers - **stdlib (2.0.220), core (0.1.37), perf (2.0.112), cache  (1.0.179), assert (1.0.7)**

Comment: Thanks for help. I noticed **core-rewriter (2.1.109)** was missing - added, redployed and its working!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that is the solution. Good catch.